# ggpredict with categorical logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, categorical-data

I have a data-frame called "student" with 4 variables. I would like to perform multivariate logistic regression with one binary dependent variable "gender" that consists of two categorical values(F-M) as Female and Male and 3 independent variables (reading_score, math_score are continues "double" and lunch as categorical "character").

To start the logistic regression I converted the gender variable into a factor (as it was not working other way). Then, I used "glm" function with "binomial" family as below:

```
student$gender <- as.factor(student$gender)
glm.fit <- glm(gender~. , data = student, family = "binomial")
```

Now I would like to plot the model with "ggpredict" function. However, I usually got the same error

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

I tried to plot it using ggpredict as below:

```
ggpredict(glm.fit) %>% plot()
```

I really tried many tutorials and I saw many questions related to this topic. I did not figure it out yet.

The propose of using ggpredict for plotting that I have 3 independent variables.

Note: A sample of the data is presented in the figure below.

[image]

Comment: It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Comment: I have edited the question and included sample of the dataset @Isaiah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the package `sjPlot` which does this very well. You may have a look [here](http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/index.html) for further explanations and examples.

As I wanted to show a plot which comes close to your data, I have created a new DF with `gender` as a binomial distributed dependent variable.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sjPlot)

set.seed(123) # set seed 

# create 1000 reading and math scores randomly
math_score = sample(60:100, 1000, replace = T)
reading_score = sample(60:100, 1000, replace = T)
# create lunch randomly from "standard" or "free"
lunch = sample(c('standard', 'free'), 1000, replace = T)

# make data frmae
student <- data.frame(
  math_score = math_score,
  reading_score = reading_score,
  lunch = as.factor(lunch)
) |> 
  # create a probability vector with some bias
  # bias is: if math_score is above its mean
  # prob is 0.8
  mutate(prob = ifelse(
    math_score > mean(math_score),
    0.8, 0.2
  )) |> 
  # create dependent variable as a binomial one
  # with prob as above
  mutate(gender = factor(
    rbinom(n = 1000, size = 1, prob = prob))) |> 
  select(-prob)

# make the fit
glm.fit <- glm(gender~., data = student, family = "binomial")

summary(glm.fit)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = gender ~ ., family = "binomial", data = student)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
#> -2.3264  -0.7876   0.3922   0.8381   2.3096  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)   -10.884194   0.877704 -12.401   <2e-16 ***
#> math_score      0.120908   0.007850  15.403   <2e-16 ***
#> reading_score   0.014737   0.006551   2.249   0.0245 *  
#> lunchstandard   0.092162   0.152221   0.605   0.5449    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 1386.2  on 999  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 1045.7  on 996  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 1053.7
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

The summary shows the expected result with `math_score` being significant.
The model can be plot as follows.

```
plot_model(
  glm.fit, 
  type = "pred", 
  terms = c("math_score", "reading_score", "lunch"), 
  colors = "bw",
  ci.lvl = NA
)
```

[image]

PS: Maybe it would be more instructive, if we could use your real data, or a part of your real data. Please have look to `dput()` as people normally do not want to type your data in. Another *Good Read* is [How make good minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Comment: it seems that i have problem of installing "sjPlot" library in my system. However, as it works in your side i will accept the answer and i will keep trying install the package. @MarBlo

Comment: You may have a look to https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/issues/640 updating some packages, especially dplyr, may solve the problem.